# Mean of an Array Created from a CSV in Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, average, mean

I am trying to find the mean of an array created from data in a CSV file using Python. Data in the array is included between a range of values, so it does not include all the values in the column of the CSV. My current code that creates the array is shown below. Several arrays have been created, but I only need to find the mean of the array called "T07s". I am consistently getting the error "cannot perform reduce with flexible type" when using the function `np.mean(T07s)`

```
import csv

class dataPoint:
    def __init__(self, V, T07, T19, T27, Time):
        self.V = V
        self.T07 = T07
        self.T19 = T19
        self.T27 = T27
        self.Time = Time

dataPoints = []
with open("data_final.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if 229 <= float(row[2]) <= 231:
            temp = dataPoint(row[1], row[12], row[24], row[32], row[0].split(" ")[1])
            dataPoints.append(temp)

T07s = np.array([x.T07 for x in dataPoints])
```

The data included in T07s is shown below:

```
for x in T07s:
    print(x)

37.2
539
435.6
717.4
587
757.9
861.8
1024.2
325
117.9
136.3
167.8
809
405.3
405.1
112.7
1317.1
1731.8
1080.2
1208.6
1212.6
1363.8
1715.3
2376.4
2563.9
2998.4
2934.7
2862.4
390.8
2332.2
2121
2237.6
2334.1
2082.2
1892.1
1888.8
1960.6
1329.1
1657.2
2042.4
1417.5
977.3
1442.8
561.2
500.3
413.3
324.1
693.7
750
865.7
434.2
635.2
815.7
171.4
829.3
815.3
774.8
1411.6
1685.1
1345.1
1193.2
1674.9
1636.4
1389.8
753.3
1102.8
908.3
1223.2
1199.4
1040.7
1040.9
824.7
620
795.7
810.4
378.8
643.2
441.8
682.8
417.8
515.6
2354.7
1938.8
1512.4
1933.5
1739.8
2281.9
1997.5
2833.4
182.8
202.4
217.3
234.2
741.9
```

Comment: Can you include some sample data in your question?

Comment: You might want to use `read_csv()` from `pandas` and then just use `.mean()` for uploaded data. Because your way of reading csv files in quite hardcore, unless it's not intentional.

Comment: if you use `numpy` then you could use [numpy.loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or [numpy.getfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)

Comment: Can you share the full CSV, or at least enough that we can understand the format?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly more of a simple solution:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data_final.csv')
data_filtered = data[data.iloc[:,2] >= 229 & data.iloc[:,2] <= 231]
print(data_filtered['T07'].mean())
```

Comment: I agree that is a simpler solution. The issue is that I am not using all of the data from the CSV file in the T07 column. It has been filtered to only include values within a range.

Comment: @Kayla added filtering to my answer

Comment: @Kayla you should check out what `pandas` is capable of. It can simplify your coding routine

Comment: Why the `[[2]]`? Not only should you be using `iloc` for that, but why even bother if the columns have names?

Comment: Trick is that I don’t know that column name

Comment: @Tino Oh yeah you’re right, neither OP’s code nor their post mention it. That’s too bad!

Comment: @AlexanderCécile ye, and you are right about `[[2]]` thing, changed to `iloc`